# center automorphisms are all inner automorphisms?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group, $Z(G)$ be the center of $G$, $\theta: G\rightarrow G$ be an automorphism of $G$. $\theta$ is called center automorphism if $g^{-1}\cdot\theta(g)\in Z(G)$, $\forall g\in G$. I am having trouble to prove that each such $\theta$ is an inner automorphism of $G$. I can show that $\theta$ is center automorphism if and only if it is commutative with any inner automorphism of $G$. This suggests that center automorphisms are contained in the center of $Inn(G)$, but I have no way to prove that. Can anyone give me a hint? Thanks.

Comment: I just realized that the statement is definitely not true for Abelian group since all inner automorphisms are trivial and all automorphisms are center automorphisms. How about non-abelian groups?

Comment: Central automorphisms are precisely those which commute with all inner automorphisms. They are usually not inner.

Comment: I quite agree with you now.

Comment: Well, that was not an opinion, really :-|

Comment: In the book "THE THEORY OF GROUPS" by Zassehhaus the following statement appears on page 148 > An automorphism which commutes with all the inner automorphisms is itself an inner automorphism. This statement is evidently not true for abelian groups.

Answer (score 0):

Every inner automorphism of the whole group must act trivially on the center, because the elements of the center commute with *every* element of the group, thus for any element of the center, $z\in Z(G)$, and any $g\in G$

$$gzg^{-1}=gg^{-1}z=ez=z$$

Sometimes, automorphisms of the center $Z(G)$ can be *extended* to automorphisms of the whole group, but not always, and not necessarily all of them in the case where some are extensible. Such automorphisms of $G$ will be *outer* automorphisms (because they cannot be inner automorphisms as shown above). This situation yields a homomorphism $\psi :\text{Out}(G)\rightarrow\text{Aut}(Z(G))$, but there is not much you can say about this in general, as far as I know.